# Mapnik server with Navteq Data

Tags: web-mapping, mapnik

Is anyone here using navteq data for a GIS app?

I'd like to work with navteq data and using mapnik-tilecache as a WMS server. The reason is, I use OSM data as well on my other server. And as the two servers need to be interchangeable I have to stick to one software technology.

Importing the .shp files in a PostGIS DB and adjust the .xml config file for the mapnik render engine seems to be the right strategy. Has anyone another idea, or can confirm this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be how I would do it. If it looks difficult to correlate OSM tags directly to Navteq fields, you may be better off creating a new Mapnik .xml. However, editing the match rules of the existing one would make it easier to make maps that look (stylistically) almost the same.